# Python Web Scraping W/O Beautiful Soup or non-default modules?

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

I'm completely and utterly new to web scraping, and have only previously used Python to make myself an IRC using sockets, ect.

What I want to do with my IRC is have the client grab an IP or list of IP's from a free blog I made using Google Blogger.

So naturally, I need to do some web scraping in order to get this information. 
The problem is, how can I do this without requiring a client downloading this to have to install addons like Beautiful Soup in order to get it working?

**Summary of Problem:**
*Need to grab some data from a webpage without the use of third party modules.*

I've done a bunch of Google'ing, but only find solutions using Beautiful Soup. (And even with that, It's hard to understand)

Comment: Maybe you can include the packet of the BeutifulSoap to the same folder as the script? This will allow you to use it without installing. Or just use regex to get all data that you need from HTML

Comment: @ton1cWhat would using regex to get the data do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import urllib2,re
content = urllib2.urlopen("http://somme.url").read()
print re.findall("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}",content)
```

something like that

Comment: Could you explain how you would modify this to persay, grab the "Press In Dire Situations" phrase at http://www.nooooooooooooooo.com/

Comment: Something like this will grab all contents of <p> tags `import urllib2,re
content = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.nooooooooooooooo.com/").read()
print re.findall(r"<p>(.+)</p>", content)`

Comment: @tonic I think you mean `"<p>([^<]+)</p>"`

Comment: @JoranBeasley I keep getting a syntax error referring to the re.findall line as invalid, and highlighting 're'. I did just as you did too....
EDIT: I am using Python 3.2, if that's of any help

Comment: I have since solved this problem. I am assigning a variable to a raw HTML dump using urllib, and searching through it using re, which was immported seperately from urllib